# C++ MFC Button on a second Dialog does nothing

Tags: c++, winapi, button, mfc, dialog

I created a C++ MFC Program with the Visual Studio Wizard. There I set the application type to "Dialog Based".

I have a button on the first dialog, which opens another dialog. I created this second dialog by right clicking on the project -> Add -> Resource -> Dialog -> New.
Then I added a MFC class to the new dialog by double clicking it in resource view.

On the **second** Dialog I also created a button. I double clicked the button and added some code which should be executed.

When I run the program and click the button on the second dialog, nothing happens and the code is not executed. I did everything like with the button on the first dialog. That one works fine. Why is the second button not working and what do I need to do?

First Dialog

```
void CMFCApplication1Dlg::OnBnClickedButton1()
{
    CDialogEx secondDialog(IDD_DIALOG1);
    secondDialog.DoModal();
}
```

Second Dialog

```
void SettingsDlg::OnBnClickedButton1()
{
    MessageBox(L"Button clicked", L"Button clicked", MB_OK);
}
```

Comment: Mandatory reading: [Message Maps (MFC)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/message-maps-mfc). That not only explains how to do it properly, but also puts you in a position to understand that the code provided is insufficient to answer the question.

Comment: Double-clicking a control on a dialog resource is a perfectly acceptable way to create a click event handler and the system should add all the boiler place code. Make sure your message map entry is also there (higher up in the class file).

Comment: Side note: You declare your variable as `CDialogEx` and your dialog is actually a `SettingsDlg` class (most likely derived from `CDialogEx`). So why not declare your variable as the right type of object ...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@andrew-truckle, your side node was the answer! I changed it to:

```
void CMFCApplication1Dlg::OnBnClickedButton1()
{
    SettingsDlg settingsDialog;
    
    settingsDialog.DoModal();
}
```

Now the button works just as expected. Thank you very much!

---

## Further Info (from @andrew-truckle)

For the benefit of others the issue here was that the original code declared the dialog like this:

```
CDialogEx secondDialog(IDD_DIALOG1);
```

That was wrong because the dialog was actually associated with the class `SettingsDlg`. This is the class that had the message map and event handlers etc. `CDialogEx` was the **base** class.

I added this update to the answer to save the reader from locating my comment to the question.